# use mutate_if by subtracting from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to do (more or less) the following

```
dplyr::mutate_if(tmp, is.numeric, function(x) x-df[3,])
```

in effect this should subtract at every `x` a value from `df`. The problem I have is that it should only use the matching column number, i.e. `tmp[x,y] - df[3,y]`.
However what's happening is that it loops over the `df[3,]` vector for every `x`, irrespective of column position.

Is there any way to make this work with `mutate_if` by indexing the column somehow, which would be my preferred solution?

here is an example:
tmp is:

```
tmp <- structure(list(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                      y = c(2, 2, 2, 2)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df (actually a matrix) is:

```
df <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
                .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y")))
```

now when I apply mutate it returns:

```
structure(list(x = c(-2, -3, -2, -3),
               y = c(-1, -2, -1, -2)),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

but I want it to be:

```
structure(list(x = c(-2, -2, -2, -2),
               y = c(-2, -2, -2, -2)),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Is *tmp* the same size as *df*?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot (temporarily) join the other table into this one and access it that way?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `purrr`:

```
df1<-as.data.frame(df)
as_tibble(purrr::map2(tmp[,purrr::map_lgl(tmp,is.numeric)],df1[3,],function(x,y) x-y))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    -2    -2
2    -2    -2
3    -2    -2
4    -2    -2
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it will get you what you want (if my understanding is correct), and then you will have to play with the formatting.  I don't quite understand why you have an entire data frame for `df` if you only care about the 3rd row.  I don't know how to index the column using `dplyr::mutate_if` either; that would be useful to know!

Since you want the columns to match, you are effectively trying to subtract each row of `tmp` from a set row of `df`.  For loops and `sapply()` are good for row-wise subtraction.

```
sapply(1:nrow(tmp), function(x) tmp[x, ] - df[3, ]) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  t()

##    x  y 
## V1 -2 -2
## V2 -2 -2
## V3 -2 -2
## V4 -2 -2
```